# BigQuery GENERATE_UUID() and CTE's

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This behavior surprised me a little bit.

When you generate a uuid in a CTE (to make a row id, etc) and reference it in the future you'll find that it changes. It seems that `generate_uuid()` is being called twice instead of once. Anyone know why this is the case w/ BigQuery and what this is called?

I was using `generate_uuid()` to create a `row_id` and was finding that in my eventual joins that no matches were occurring because of this. Best way to get around it I've found is by just creating a table from the first CTE which cements the uuid in place for future use.

Still curious to know more about the why and what behind this.

```sql
with _first as (

  select generate_uuid() as row_id
  
)
,_second as (

  select * from _first
  
)

select row_id from _first
union all
select row_id from _second
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> curious to know more about the why and what behind this

This is by design:

WITH clauses are not materialized. Placing all your queries in WITH clauses and then running UNION ALL is a misuse of the WITH clause.
If a query appears in more than one WITH clause, **`it executes in each clause`**.

You can see in documentation - [Do not treat WITH clauses as prepared statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-communication#do_not_treat_with_clauses_as_prepared_statements)

Comment: Yes - thank you for pointing me to that. I assumed it was by design, but that very clear explanation came up in 0 searches I did. Probably because it's buried in "Optimizing communication between slots". My use case was a little less straightforward than my example. My real use was in CTE 1 creating a unique key per row, then twice manipulating that data in two separate CTE 2 & 3. The resulting join between 1, 2 & 3 fails because of this. My solution, as I said was to materialize CTE 1 in a table.

Comment: More color: I was